# Change the active Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I'm looking for a way to set the active window. The only solutions I found are outdated. They included modules like `pywinauto` but its `focus()` function doesn't work.

I need something that quickly switches/makes another window active.

I tried the code below, but it doesn't work as it says `object has no attribute 'focus'`

```
import pygetwindow as gw

win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Photoshop')[0]
win.focus()
```

I am using Windows 8

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Windows. Updated first post too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the object method you're after is `activate`:

```
>>> help(win.activate)
Help on method activate in module 
pygetwindow._pygetwindow_win:

activate() method of 
pygetwindow._pygetwindow_win.Win32Window instance
    Activate this window and make it the foreground window.
```

So changing your code as follows should work.

```
import pygetwindow as gw

win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Photoshop')[0]
win.activate()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the accepted answer is only for Windows, here is a **Linux solution** for most major distributions:

1. Install [PyWinCtl](https://github.com/Kalmat/PyWinCtl#pywinctl-) and the dependency *tkinter*

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-tk
   pip install PyWinCtl
   ```
2. Change the import in the example code from above

   ```
   import pywinctl as gw
   win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Signal')[0]
   win.activate()
   ```